# Windows 10: normal system sounds but can't listen to mp3 and some youtube videos (too low)?

Tags: windows-10, audio, mp3, youtube

Recently my PC has started to show some weird sound behavior. I think that maybe it began after a Windows 10 update, but I'm not sure.

I've tried:

- Clean uninstall / install of both Video and Audio drivers (using [DDU](https://www.guru3d.com/files-get/display-driver-uninstaller-download,1.html))
- Changing audio format (currently in 44100Hz - 16bits)
- All sorts of audio configs properties (picture below)
- Installed the latest drivers

[image]

I can't play an mp3 file. I mean, it runs but you can barely hear the sound, and you hear some squishing sound. It's like some CODEC is missing (is this still a thing?).

Some Youtube videos work fine, other videos the volume is TOO LOW and it sounds just like the mp3 file. I guess maybe some youtube videos have different formats, I don't know.

I'm almost giving up and trying to re-install Windows from scratch.

Comment: This isn’t a codec issue.  Do you have any applications similar to that of TeamViewer installed?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't. It was some weird thing. I've posted an answer on how I resolved this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but the way I've resolved this issue was the following:

- I've balanced 100% on the LEFT side of the speaker.
- I'm using headphones, actually. I haven't tested on a speaker.

There were evenly balanced, I think they were set as 67 / 67.

- Weird things:

  - Systems sounds were completely normal the whole time. And still are fine.
  - This was only occurring in some youtube videos, some mp3 files, etc.
  - Some youtube videos were not having any issues.
  - Sounds were coming out of both sides of the headphones.
  - Sounds **STILL** are coming out of both sides of the headphones.
  - Those some headphones were working fine on all videos and mp3 files before this began to happen. So I don't think this was related to this specific headphone, like some mono/stereo compatibility.

Now everything seems normal. All videos play just fine.

[image]